# Python: How do i run a function simultaneously as other code and update the other Code real time?

Tags: python, pygame

I've recently started coding with pygame to create a GUI Radar for a Project which requires real time radar. The problem i've came across is that i want to run the Ultra() function at the same time as the rest of the code allowing me to have real time updates of the "Distance" variable. And i want this Distance variable to update a label on the screen. Any help at all would be greatly appreciated . Thanks!

```
import pygame
import time
import sys
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import os

BLACK = (0,0,0)
WHITE = (255,255,255)
RED = (255,0,0)
GREEN = (0,155,0)
BLUE = (0,0,255)

pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
menuW = 400
menuH = 250


mainDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((menuW, menuH))
pygame.display.set_caption("Radar ALPHA 1.0")

#FONTS
fontSmall = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 25)
fontBig = pygame.font.SysFont(None , 50)
#HOMEMADE FUNCTIONS


def ultra():
    global Distance
    GPIO.setwarnings(False)

    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

    TRIG = 7
    ECHO = 11

    GPIO.setup(TRIG,GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(TRIG,0)

    GPIO.setup(ECHO,GPIO.IN)

    time.sleep(1)
    print "Starting mesurement..."

    GPIO.output(TRIG,1)
    time.sleep(0.00001)
    GPIO.output(TRIG,0)

    while GPIO.input(ECHO) == 0:
        pass
    start = time.time()

    while GPIO.input(ECHO) == 1:
        pass
    stop = time.time()

    Distance = (stop-start) * 17000

    print Distance , " CM"


def message_small(msg,colour,width,height):
    screen_text = fontSmall.render(msg, True, colour)
    mainDisplay.blit(screen_text, [width, height])


def message_big(msg,colour,width,height):
    screen_text = fontBig.render(msg, True, colour)
    mainDisplay.blit(screen_text, [width, height])

def circle(display,r):
    pygame.draw.circle(display, WHITE, [500, 360], r, 3)

def button(bPosX,bPosY,bX,bY):
    pygame.draw.rect(mainDisplay, GREEN, [bPosX, bPosY, bX, bY] )



menuOn = True
guiOn = True
radarOn = True
dataOn = True
infoOn = True


 #VARs
radarSetup = True
ultraSetup = True
targetSpeed = 5

targetX = 200
targetY = 100

changeTX = 0
changeTY = 0



#MAIN BIT
while guiOn:

    while menuOn:
        #VARs and SETUP
        mainDisplay.fill(WHITE)
        message_big("Radar Menu ALPHA 1.0", RED, 5,5)
        message_small("Press R to go to Radar", BLACK, 5,50)
        message_small("Press D to go to Data", BLACK , 5, 70)
        message_small("Press I to go to Info" , BLACK, 5, 90)
        message_small("Press Q to Quit" , BLACK, 250,220)


        pygame.display.update()


        #EVENT HANDLER
        for event in pygame.event.get():

            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                menuOn = False
                radarOn = False
                dataOn = False
                infoOn = False
                guiOn = False

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_r:
                    menuOn = False
                    dataOn = False
                    infoOn = False

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                    menuOn = False
                    radarOn = False
                    infoOn = False


            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_i:
                    menuOn = False
                    radarOn = False
                    dataOn = False

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                    radarOn = False
                    dataOn = False
                    infoOn = False
                    guiOn = False
                    menuOn = False
        #LOGICS


    while radarOn:

        while radarSetup:
            pygame.init()
            clock = pygame.time.Clock()
            menuW = 1000
            menuH = 720
            radarDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((menuW, menuH))
            pygame.display.set_caption("Radar ALPHA 1.0")
            radarSetup = False

        #CLEAR and setup
        radarDisplay.fill(WHITE)
        message_big("RADAR v1.0",RED, 400 , 20)




        #EVENT HANDLER
        for event in pygame.event.get():

            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                menuOn = False
                radarOn = False
                dataOn = False
                infoOn = False
                guiOn = False

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    changeTX =  - targetSpeed

                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    changeTX = targetSpeed

                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    changeTY =  - targetSpeed


                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    changeTY = targetSpeed



            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    changeTX = 0

                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    changeTX = 0

                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    changeTY = 0


                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    changeTY = 0





        #Circle Set UP

        pygame.draw.circle(radarDisplay, BLACK, [menuW/2, menuH/2], 300)            
        pygame.draw.circle(radarDisplay, GREEN, [menuW/2, menuH/2], 20)
        circle(radarDisplay,50)
        circle(radarDisplay,100)
        circle(radarDisplay,150)
        circle(radarDisplay,200)
        circle(radarDisplay,250)    

        #LOGICS

        targetX += changeTX
        targetY += changeTY


        pygame.draw.circle(radarDisplay, RED, [targetX, targetY], 5)

        pygame.display.update()

        clock.tick(2)

    while dataOn:
        #CLEAR
        mainDisplay.fill(WHITE)
        message_small("DATA",RED, 150 , 100)
        pygame.display.update()

        #VARs

        #EVENT HANDLER
        for event in pygame.event.get():

            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                menuOn = False
                radarOn = False
                dataOn = False
                infoOn = False
                guiOn = False

        #LOGICS


    while infoOn:

        #CLEAR
        mainDisplay.fill(WHITE)
        message_small("INFO",RED, 150 , 100)
        pygame.display.update()

        #VARs

        #EVENT HANDLER
        for event in pygame.event.get():

            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                menuOn = False
                radarOn = False
                dataOn = False
                infoOn = False
                guiOn = False

        #LOGICS




    clock.tick(10)
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: Possibly `threading`

Comment: Threads are your answer. They allow for concurrently running code. Be weary however threads are the (not in every case) pitfal of (C)python. Take a look at the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL) here https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock

Comment: Depending on what you mean by "real time", that's not really achievable in python. If you just mean non-blocking/concurrenty, look into the `threading` or `multiprocessing` modules

Comment: Don't you have a mainloop where everything runs?  Can you not put it inside? What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Threads run separately from your code. If you are sharing data between threads make sure they are thread safe object that contain the data otherwise you get read after write errors or other errors from when the data has been change. https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/threading.html

The other way is using the multiprocessing library which is for some major processing.

```
import threading
import queue
import time

def mymethod(storage, stop):
    """Continuously add counters to the given storage queue.

    Args:
        storage (queue.Queue): Hold the data.
        stop (threading.Event): Thread safe signal for when to quit.
    """
    counter = 0
    while not stop.is_set():
        storage.put(counter)
        counter += 1
        time.sleep(0.1)
# end mymethod

if __name__ == "__main__":
    storage = queue.Queue()
    stop = threading.Event()

    th = threading.Thread(target=mymethod, args=(storage, stop))
    # th.daemon = True # Daemon threads are cleaned up automatically
    th.start() # Run

    for i in range(10):
        # We don't actually know how fast each program runs. Order will not be saved.
        print(storage.get(0)) # Pull the thread counter number. 0 means no wait
        storage.put(i) # Set my counter number
        time.sleep(0.2) # Just to show things aren't happening in any order.
    time.sleep(1) # Do other stuff and forget about it.

    stop.set() # Clear the stop signal, so the thread can leave the loop and quit
    th.join(0) # Safely close the thread when it is done

    print("thread closed")
    while not storage.empty():
        print(storage.get(0))
```

Comment: Explain better your answer. I can also copy from the internet easily.